# Starting activemq service in Linux gets the message: “Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/activemq; bad; vendor preset: enabled)”

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

My activemq was suddenly down (not sure why). When I try to start the service by

```
sudo service activemq starts
```

It seems fine. However, when I check the status using

```
sudo service activemq status
```

I got the following message.

```
activemq.service - LSB: Starts ActiveMQ
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/activemq; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Fri 2018-03-30 19:51:54 UTC; 44min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 1253 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/activemq start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 0
   Memory: 0B
      CPU: 0

Mar 30 19:51:54 ip-172-31-43-187 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Starts ActiveMQ...
Mar 30 19:51:54 ip-172-31-43-187 activemq[1253]: INFO: Loading '/etc/default/activemq'
Mar 30 19:51:54 ip-172-31-43-187 activemq[1253]: INFO: Using java '/usr/bin/java'
Mar 30 19:51:54 ip-172-31-43-187 activemq[1253]: INFO: Starting - inspect logfiles specified in logging.properties and log4j.properties to get details
Mar 30 19:51:54 ip-172-31-43-187 activemq[1253]: INFO: changing to user 'activemq' to invoke java
Mar 30 19:51:54 ip-172-31-43-187 su[1352]: Successful su for activemq by root
Mar 30 19:51:54 ip-172-31-43-187 su[1352]: + ??? root:activemq
Mar 30 19:51:54 ip-172-31-43-187 su[1352]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user activemq by (uid=0)
Mar 30 19:51:54 ip-172-31-43-187 activemq[1253]: INFO: pidfile created : '/etc//data/activemq.pid' (pid '1370')
Mar 30 19:51:54 ip-172-31-43-187 systemd[1]: Started LSB: Starts ActiveMQ.
```

Note that if I use `ps aux`, I can find the activemq pid. I am currently using AWS free tier. And my Linux server system is

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

Any ideas? guys. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might be hitting a bug
[Ubuntu activemq bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/activemq/+bug/1733853)

instead of `sudo service activemq starts`

try `systemctl start activemq.service`  which also may fail

finally try `/etc/init.d/activemq console main` and keep an eye on the bug.

good luck